# AngularJS $scope data across different pages

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I'm getting to grips with AngularJS and I am working on an application just now where I have questions and answers.

The questions use an incrementing `+` and `-` button per item which updates the `$scope`

What I am wondering though, because I will have to access the values from the question side of the app in the answers, what would be the simplest way to get this across. I had thought of storing the $scope.questions into localstorage.

```
{
    "uid" : 1,
    "name": "Quiz",
    "drinks" : [
        {
            "id" : 0,
            "type" : "Footballs",
            "image" : "http://placehold.it/280x300",
            "amount" : ""
        },
        {
            "id" : 1,
            "type" : "Golf Balls",
            "image" : "http://placehold.it/280x300",
            "amount" : ""
        }
]
}
```

The above is json which is fed into my page and then using ng-repeat it will display and then the `amount` keys get updated when the user has clicked either `+` or `-`.

I would like to somehow update this json to be accessable throughout the site too so that when the user/client has updated it they can view a separate page which shows them the answers.

Comment: Is your app a true single page app or are you only using Angular for the bindings?

Comment: look into angular services.  They are singletons which are great for persisting data across multiple views.

Comment: As tymeJV hinted, if you have a single page application with various views (HTML Partials) it is very easy to pass the data between these using services, factories, even (shudder) global variables. If on the other hand you are posting back to the server, passing data between completely refreshed pages is a different story. More information on this would be helpful!

Comment: @tymeJV it isn't a single page app andular is used for the bindings, although is it easy to change this and do it as a single page and have different views?

Comment: @Donald -- Ideally Angular is used for Single Page Apps since you can then use services and factories to share data. If you simply use it for the bindings you'll want to use some kind of `session`, cache, or local storage to persist the data. I use Angular on an enterprise app for bindings only and cache as much of the data as possible in Redis

Comment: @tymeJV I have come across https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_07 which I will look into. If not I might look into a noSQL alternative

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used `localStorage` to carry data from the $scope around

```
localStorage.setItem('data', angular.toJson($scope.data));
```